# Как достать крайнее значение select из дерева категорий?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Всем привет. есть такая функция,

```
function get_cat_options($parentID, $db) {
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM `cat` WHERE `parent` = '. intval($parentID) .';';
  $res = mysqli_query($db, $query);
  ob_start();
  $rows = mysqli_num_rows($res);
  $i = 0;
  if ($rows > 0) {?>
    <select name="cat" class="row-item-2 subcat">
        <option value=""><?= 'Категория'?></option>
        <? while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)) {?>
          <option value="<? echo $row->id; ?>" <? echo $rows == ++$i ? 'selected' : ''; ?>><?  echo $row->name; ?></option>
        <?}?>
    </select>
  <?} else {?>
    <span class="subcat" style="color:green">OK!</span>
  <?}
  return ob_get_clean();
}
$cat = get_cat_options(0, $on_link);
```

Она достает дерево категорий из БД в таком формате

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У категорий разный уровень вложенности от 2 до 5, подскажите как  достать value последнего выбранного значения?

Достаю таким методом, но он берет значение только первого уровня (недвижимость).

```
fields.cat = self.find('select[name="cat"]').val();
```

К примеру:

1. Недвижимость -> Квартиры -> Сдам (необходимо взять это значение)
2. Бытовая электроника -> Телевизоры (необходимо взять это значение)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас создаётся много элементов select с одинаковым именем "name='cat'". 
Можете указать другое имя для селекта, добавив имя родителя:
`<select name="cat_by_parent_<?=$parentID;?>" class="row-item-2 subcat">`

Тогда последняя категория будет:
`fields.cat = self.find('select[name^="cat_by_parent_"]').last().val();`

Comment: Спасибо, большое!